# Hiding a HTML element if all its contained Wicket components are invisible

Tags: wicket

I have a HTML element which is hidden if its contained Wicket component `foo` is invisible.

```
<span class="ig" wicket:enclosure="foo">
  <span class="iga">
    <span wicket:id="foo"/>
  </span>
</span>
```

Now I have to add a second Wicket component `bar` and the enclosure should only show up if `foo` or `bar` are visible. Something like this:

```
<span class="ig" wicket:enclosure="foo-or-bar???">
  <span class="iga">
    <span wicket:id="foo"/>
    <span wicket:id="bar"/>
  </span>
</span>
```

But how? One complication is, that the visibility of the components can change by AJAX events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the logic to your Java code!

```
Component foo = ...
Component bar = ...
WebMarkupContainer wrapper = new WebMarkupContainer("wrapper") {
  @Override public void onConfigure() {
    super.onConfigure();
    foo.configure();
    bar.configure();
    setVisible(foo.isVisible() && bar.isVisible());
  }
};
wrapper.add(foo);
wrapper.add(bar);
add(wrapper);


<span class="ig" wicket:id="wrapper">
  <span class="iga">
    <span wicket:id="foo"/>
    <span wicket:id="bar"/>
  </span>
</span>
```

P.S. I recommend you to avoid using `wicket:enclosure` in almost every case! There are plenty of corner cases where it breaks. You may check Wicket JIRA for examples.

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason with your code the span is now always visible even if both components are invisible.

Comment: I looked into the code. The visibility of the components is set in their onInitialize(), more exactly in the onConfigure of an AjaxLink which is added in onInitialize. Is that maybe called after the onConfigure() of the wrapper?

Comment: The visibility of the component can also change in onEvent(). So it's not that easy. Is there something like a VisibilityListener?

Comment: Right! You need to configure foo and bar before setting the wrapper's visibility. I've updated the answer.